# How to reduce the false positives to improve the models performance?

Tags: machine-learning-model, ensemble-modeling, performance, binary-classification, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I am currently building a binary classification model to predict order return rates. I used the GradientBoostingClassifier for training the model and also performed hyperparameter tuning using RandomizedSearchCV. Currently, the metrics for the test data are as follows:

- Precision: 0.683
- Recall: 0.78
- F1 score: 0.72
- Accuracy: 0.66
- ROC-AUC: 0.74

The images below show the data distribution of the target label and the confusion matrix.
[image]
[image]

I can also see from the feature importance that the brand feature has around 70% importance. If a particular brand has many return entries than sale entries, the prediction also has more returns than sales, which is leading to false positives.

I tried assigning the sample weights to the true labels, undersampling, and SNORT techniques to balance the data, but none of them helped in improving the performance. I also tried using XGBoost, but it didn't make much of a difference.

What can I do to reduce the false positives in this case and improve the performance of the model?

Comment: I would say the main problem is class imbalance. Data are mostly about returns. Either try to get more balanced data, or maybe try oversampling like SMOTE.

Comment: i balanced the data and now the false negatives increased and false positives decreased.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not mention based on which metric your decision will be drawn (e.g. if model A has better F1 but model B is better on ROC-AUC, which would you pick?) nor much detail on your dataset, I can only give some general advice.

1. Adjust the cost matrix: if false positive is a concern, try increasing the cost for false positives. This is a little-effort option, but you may end up having more false negative instead.
2. Invest in feature engineering: a model can only learn what you feed in. This requires a lot of work (and creativity), but is the ultimate solution.
3. Ensembling: train different types of models and ensemble them.